# Создание переменной ссылочного типа при каждой итерации цикла. Это затратно?

Tags: c#, оптимизация, инспекция-кода, рефакторинг

Есть вот такой код:

```
...
Match match;
foreach (var value in egeQuestionValues)
{
    match = Regex.Match(value, $@"(?<={number}\()\d+(?=.*%\))");
    if (!match.Success)
        throw new ArgumentException($"The record {value} is incorrect", nameof(egeQuestionValues));

    egeQuestionIntValues.Add(int.Parse(match.Value));                
}

return egeQuestionIntValues.Average();
```

Я создал переменную `match` специально вне цикла `foreach`, чтобы в рантайме не создать ее при каждой итерации. Делал, думаю что это затратно. Но ReSharper мне советует отрефакторить этот код таким образом:

```
...
foreach (var value in egeQuestionValues)
{
    var match = Regex.Match(value, $@"(?<={number}\()\d+(?=.*%\))");
    if (!match.Success)
        throw new ArgumentException($"The record {value} is incorrect", nameof(egeQuestionValues));

    egeQuestionIntValues.Add(int.Parse(match.Value));                
}

return egeQuestionIntValues.Average();
```

т.е. сейчас при каждой итерации переменная `match` будет создаваться каждый раз. **Разве это не затратно?** ReSharper советует поступать так не только с типом `Match` и с другими типами так было.

Comment: Подозреваю, что компилятор сам оптимизирует эту ситуацию.

Comment: @Bulson т.е. вы подозреваете что IL-код для второго сценария  будет построен по моему сценарию?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Разницы особой нету.

Все переменные ссылочного типа без инициализации автоматически инициализируются null-значением.

Что сама по себе переменная ссылочного типа? Это переменная, которая ссылается на какой-то адрес.

Смена ссылки - это быстрая операция, так как не создается никаких дополнительных объектов, как это происходит со значимым типом.

Скорее всего, компилятор приведет код к первому случаю и IL-код будет идентичным.

На мой взгляд овчинка выделки не стоит и это не узкое место, ведь вы программируете на высокоуровневом языке программирования, где на первое место нужно ставить понятность кода, а уж потом если где-то что-то тормозит, то оптимизировать.

Второй вариант более приятен, так как переменная находится прямо в месте ее использования и можно сразу понять, что за циклом она нигде использоваться не будет.

Answer (score 5):

Я что-то отличий не вижу, но может кто чего заметит пусть сигнализирует

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Person> people1 = GetWithVarInWhile();

    List<Person> people2 = GetWithVarOutWhile();
}

private static List<Person> GetWithVarInWhile()
{
    List<Person> result = new List<Person>();

    int i = 10;
    while (i > 0)
    {
        var p = new Person { Name = $"Name{i}" };
        result.Add(p);
        i--;
    }

    return result;
}

private static List<Person> GetWithVarOutWhile()
{
    List<Person> result = new List<Person>();

    int i = 10;
    Person person = null;
    while (i > 0)
    {
        person = new Person { Name = $"Name{i}" };
        result.Add(person);
        i--;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Вот первый

```
.method private hidebysig static class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<class ConsoleWhile.Person> 
    GetWithVarInWhile() cil managed
{
  // Размер кода:       71 (0x47)
  .maxstack  4
  .locals init ([0] class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<class ConsoleWhile.Person> result,
       [1] int32 i,
       [2] class ConsoleWhile.Person p,
       [3] bool V_3,
       [4] class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<class ConsoleWhile.Person> V_4)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  newobj     instance void class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<class ConsoleWhile.Person>::.ctor()
  IL_0006:  stloc.0
  IL_0007:  ldc.i4.s   10
  IL_0009:  stloc.1
  IL_000a:  br.s       IL_0037
  IL_000c:  nop
  IL_000d:  newobj     instance void ConsoleWhile.Person::.ctor()
  IL_0012:  dup
  IL_0013:  ldstr      "Name{0}"
  IL_0018:  ldloc.1
  IL_0019:  box        [mscorlib]System.Int32
  IL_001e:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Format(string,
                                                          object)
  IL_0023:  callvirt   instance void ConsoleWhile.Person::set_Name(string)
  IL_0028:  nop
  IL_0029:  stloc.2
  IL_002a:  ldloc.0
  IL_002b:  ldloc.2
  IL_002c:  callvirt   instance void class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<class ConsoleWhile.Person>::Add(!0)
  IL_0031:  nop
  IL_0032:  ldloc.1
  IL_0033:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0034:  sub
  IL_0035:  stloc.1
  IL_0036:  nop
  IL_0037:  ldloc.1
  IL_0038:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0039:  cgt
  IL_003b:  stloc.3
  IL_003c:  ldloc.3
  IL_003d:  brtrue.s   IL_000c
  IL_003f:  ldloc.0
  IL_0040:  stloc.s    V_4
  IL_0042:  br.s       IL_0044
  IL_0044:  ldloc.s    V_4
  IL_0046:  ret
} // end of method Program::GetWithVarInWhile
```

А вот второй

```
    .method private hidebysig static class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<class ConsoleWhile.Person> 
    GetWithVarOutWhile() cil managed
{
  // Размер кода:       73 (0x49)
  .maxstack  4
  .locals init ([0] class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<class ConsoleWhile.Person> result,
       [1] int32 i,
       [2] class ConsoleWhile.Person person,
       [3] bool V_3,
       [4] class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<class ConsoleWhile.Person> V_4)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  newobj     instance void class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<class ConsoleWhile.Person>::.ctor()
  IL_0006:  stloc.0
  IL_0007:  ldc.i4.s   10
  IL_0009:  stloc.1
  IL_000a:  ldnull
  IL_000b:  stloc.2
  IL_000c:  br.s       IL_0039
  IL_000e:  nop
  IL_000f:  newobj     instance void ConsoleWhile.Person::.ctor()
  IL_0014:  dup
  IL_0015:  ldstr      "Name{0}"
  IL_001a:  ldloc.1
  IL_001b:  box        [mscorlib]System.Int32
  IL_0020:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Format(string,
                                                          object)
  IL_0025:  callvirt   instance void ConsoleWhile.Person::set_Name(string)
  IL_002a:  nop
  IL_002b:  stloc.2
  IL_002c:  ldloc.0
  IL_002d:  ldloc.2
  IL_002e:  callvirt   instance void class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<class ConsoleWhile.Person>::Add(!0)
  IL_0033:  nop
  IL_0034:  ldloc.1
  IL_0035:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0036:  sub
  IL_0037:  stloc.1
  IL_0038:  nop
  IL_0039:  ldloc.1
  IL_003a:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_003b:  cgt
  IL_003d:  stloc.3
  IL_003e:  ldloc.3
  IL_003f:  brtrue.s   IL_000e
  IL_0041:  ldloc.0
  IL_0042:  stloc.s    V_4
  IL_0044:  br.s       IL_0046
  IL_0046:  ldloc.s    V_4
  IL_0048:  ret
} // end of method Program::GetWithVarOutWhile
```

Answer (score 4):

Компиляторы сейчас практически никогда не компилируют код вот прямо так, как написано в программе. Они стали намного умнее, чем были во времена Кернигана и Ричи.

Если у вас появляется переменная, а потом исчезает, и появляется другая переменная, компилятор не будет наивно освобождать память, чтобы тут же снова её выделить. Он заметит, что новую переменную можно использовать место от старой переменной, и так и сделает.

Смысла «помочь» компилятору и соптимизировать такие вот мелочи за него нет никакого: компилятор делает это, поверьте, куда лучше нас с вами.

Если вы хотите соптимизировать, лучше пытаться улучшать алгоритмы. Переход от квадратичного алгоритма к логарифмическому даст заметное ускорение и улучшение производительности; выигрыш одной локальной переменной, даже если и имел бы какие-то преимущества, принёс бы вам существенно меньше микросекунды, и всё равно никем не был бы замечен.